# Using nginx-ingess to access an application in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a bare metal Kubernetes (1 master and 3 nodes) and using metallb to provide load-balancing.
I also have Jupyterhub and nginx-ingress installed as services.

**nginx-ingress:**

```
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.108.54.171   192.168.1.240   80:31463/TCP,443:30231/TCP   5m11s
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.98.47.19     <none>          80/TCP                       5m11s
```

**Jupyterhub**

```
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
proxy-public   LoadBalancer   10.102.251.6    192.168.1.242   80:32691/TCP,443:31737/TCP   8h
```

I can access the jupyterhub from the external IP BUT cannot access it thru the nginx-ingress

**nginx-ingress config.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
ingress
     enabled: true
     hosts:
kind: Ingress
metadata:
     annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
     name: myingress
     namespace: default
rbac:
   create: true
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        serviceName: jhub
        servicePort: 80
      path: /classes
```

My question is, how do I access the jupyterhub (proxy-public) via nginx-ingress

Answer (score 1):

The `proxy-public` backend service should be of type ClusterIP instead of type LoadBalancer just like the `nginx-ingress-default-backend` service. The service name in ingress should be `proxy-public` instead of `jhub`.

You should be able to access it via `http://192.168.1.240/classes`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a DNS record or hosts file entry pointing `example.com` (maybe change this) to the external IP of the ingress controller (`192.168.1.240`).

The ingress controller will only route requests to the service backend defined in the ingress if if the URI of the request matches the `host` field in the ingress.